# Object Debugger gives me Extraneous Property And Inferred Property error on opg

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have everything right in my header. I followed the Dev Doc for adding my location and address to my header but I get these warnings. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:language.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:email.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:phone_number.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:fax_number.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:latitude.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:longitude.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:street-address.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:locality.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:region.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:postal-code.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:country-name.
Inferred Property   The og:locale property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmodelcrowd.com

Comment: Just so everybody knows: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 2):

now facebook require you to add og:locale to meta tag too

they just require when they announce new open graph beta

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="fr_FR" />
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/internationalization/

Answer (score 0):

The link in your comment doesn't spit out any errors. Were you putting old Meta tags on your page?

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem try to read this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/internationalization/

use this

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_us" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="ar_ar" /> <!-- optional -->
```