# Facebook Open Graph and Metatags

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

I have the following output at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

I added the `locale` metatag, because I had a lot of **Extraneous Property** errors. But that does not solve it.

```
Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:latitude
Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:longitude.
Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:region.
Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:street-address.
Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:locality.
Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:postal-code.
Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:country-name.
Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:email.
Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:phone_number.
Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:fax_number.
```

I also have the namespaces in the `<html>` tag:

```
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" 
    xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

I have also tried `xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"`
as suggested here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

My doctype is `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">`

I have checked this thread [Facebook Open Graph locale for Australia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707648/facebook-open-graph-locale-for-australia) and this [Object Debugger gives me Extraneous Property And Inferred Property error on opg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563538/object-debugger-gives-me-extraneous-property-and-inferred-property-error-on-opg)

But I still have the **Extraneous Property** error

**Edit:** I used this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#extra-data When I browse to the namespace definition of open graph, I don't see the latitude and longtitude options, but Facebook's documentation does recommend it. But the debugger of Facebook does not accepts it. I am missing something here...

**Edit2:** I have:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="company" />
```

but Facebook says: https://graph.facebook.com/10150616664862786

**type: website**
???

**Why does Facebook see a different type? And how do I fix this?**

Comment: Can you give a link to your site please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because even though you have specified og:type=company, the linter is showing that your type is website, and the properties you are trying to use are not applicable for a website object type. There is an accepted answer for this [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8263493/ogtype-and-valid-values-constantly-being-parsed-as-ogtype-website). Your real problem is that the linter is reading og:type incorrectly.

Comment: But company is a valid type. it is listed here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#types

Comment: Yes. But it clearly isn't working for you so something must be amiss. The reason why you have that error message is because type=website cannot have those properties. So now you need an answer to why is it seeing type website instead of type company. There are three or four SO questions on this already if you search. The one I linked to is the first I saw with an accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's documentation is out of date, (big surprise there.) The only allowed og:types can be found [here](http://ogp.me/#types), none of which are company.

Answer (score 0):

You should also remember to add `namespace declaration` to the head and body tags of your page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 
   <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns# YOUR_NAMESPACE: http://ogp.me/ns/apps/YOUR_NAMESPACE#"> 
     <meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR_APP_ID" /> 
     <meta ...
```

Obviously, replace `YOUR_NAMESPACE` and `YOUR_APP_ID` with your app's settings.